# Incorrect image source in WPF application in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want to add an image in my WPF application. I want the image to be embedded so that the application can load that image from any system and not just mine. I searched and found some solutions. Changed my build action to Resources. But on hovering the mouse on the source, it is showing a different path as of my workspace. What is the problem? (Incorrect path in the image attached)

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="144" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="519" Background="#FFA02C2C" >
      <Image x:Name="image"  Grid.Row="0" Source="FriendsRandomEpisode;component/Images/Friends.jpg"/>
</DockPanel>
```

[This image shows the incorrect path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkOjG.png)

Comment: Try to set the the path like: `Source="Images/Friends.jpg"`

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Okay great. It worked. Thanks a lot. Submit the answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set any component in the source if the image is in the same component. Simply set the source like

```
Source="Images/Friends.jpg"
```